# Output of zawgyi and unicode font inconsistent with string in dictionary

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

So I need the front end of my unity engine to be displaying the fonts (from myanmar) exactly the same as what I have in my code (strings)for unity. When it renders in my mobile device, for some reason, the .ttf file compiles and recognizes my fonts differently than the one i have in my code.

I tried removing all related myanmar .ttf files in my apk, letting it default to android's fonts, but it outputs the same as what I have for my ttf, which is different from the written ones in the code base.

```
 public static Dictionary<string, string[]> s = new Dictionary<string, string[]> 
    { 
         { "PolicyText", new string[] 
             { "Privacy Policy", "ကိုယ်ရေးအချက်လက်", "ကိုယ္ေရးအခ်က္လက္"     } 
         }
    };
```

it should display exactly the same as the code, but it is different when rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sharing an update on this. Got a solution for myself. It seems, Unity has some rendering issue if i put the string in directly like this. For those who wish to translate it to Burmese, the input will have to be in zawgyi encoded and translated via zawgyi.ttf file

Comment: Could you be a little more specific in your answer? I'm looking for a solution similar to yours (if not exactly the same), but I can't find out what to do from your answer. Thanks :)